# Run sqlquery on multiple server using Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I am trying to run this query

select mirroring_role_desc from sys.database_mirroring where database_id > 4 and mirroring_state is NOT NULL

So the query will basically output the number of databases and just show principal/mirror
like this
[image]

I want this query to output to excel file another interesting thing, if any one database in the instance is prinicial/mirror then we can assume the whole instance as principal/mirror.
So in the excel file I want one column with servername\hostname and then the next column to show if it is mirror or principal or none (if none just leave blank) How to do this?

I have tried this,

```
$ServerInstance = "server1\instance1a "
$Database = " "
$ConnectionTimeout = 30
$Query = "select mirroring_role_desc from sys.database_mirroring where database_id > 4 and mirroring_state is NOT NULL"
$QueryTimeout = 120

$conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
$ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $ServerInstance,$Database,$ConnectionTimeout
$conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
$conn.Open()
$cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
$cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
$ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
$da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
[void]$da.fill($ds)
$conn.Close()
$ds.Tables
```

frankly the above code is working fine but the problem is getting the instance name and only single column with principal/mirror INTO a excel file, that is the issue that I am having.

To get a better idea this is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Did you try the basic Google queries like https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sql+get+server+name ?

Comment: What output do you want? Can you provide a one-line sample output?

Comment: @ChadMiller pls see my edit in OP

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post a while back to run a script across all servers in a central management server. You should be able to adapt it fairly easily. Check it out [here](http://www.spartansql.com/2012/10/changing-job-ownership-across-all.html).

Comment: I don't want to engage CMS cause it only accepts Windows Authentication and in my current environment that is useless

Comment: Ah... but if you notice, my approach only gets the server names from the CMS. How you authenticate to each server after that is up to you. There's no reason that you couldn't use SQL auth once you get the name.